# Executing a tr command on a queue?

Tags: c, linux, queue, client-server, exec

I have a server and client application, using IPC queues. The server is (for now) simply sending back the text received from the client. I would like the server to change the letters in the message from lower to upper case. I'm wondering how to achieve it. Do I have to create a pipe? I'm thinking about 'grabbing' the text from the received queue, executing the tr command on it and sending back to the client. But if using a pipe, from where do I get the file descriptors? I mean, `int fds[2];` and `pipe(fds);` gives me a pipe, but it's not working on two char arrays like this:

```
int fds[2];
pipe(fds);
char a[100];
char b[100];
fds[0] = open(a,O_RDOLNY);
fds[1] = open(b,O_WRONLY);
```

How can I execute a tr command on a text held by a message queue?

Comment: I'm confused.  You have server/client written in C and communicating via queues?  Why do you need to have `tr` enter into this?  Can't you just read the input queue, change the case (cnicutar provided the code), and write the output queue?  It is only one little step more than what you are already doing.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't `fork` a program for this:

```
p = str;
while (*p) {
    *p = toupper(*p);
    p++;
}
```

More seriously, you should probably use `popen` that automatically (and robustly) forks and uses a pipe to setup a `FILE *` for you.

```
FILE *cmd = popen("tr ... ", "r");
```

And then simple `fgets` from it (don't forget to `pclose` it). Sadly on Linux you can't write and read to a popened file at the same time (you can on FreeBSD).

#### EDIT

Since this is a homework question (and frankly because I don't think it's trivial to get it completely right at this time of night), here is what `popen` actually does:

- Create a pipe
- Fork a shell that will run the command
- Return a `FILE *` (possibly via `fdopen`)

The last step is really optional as you could always read from the file descriptor directly.

Comment: it might be a school exercise where one would be forced to use multiple processes such that concurrency and resource sharing concepts are taught.

Comment: @Alex You might be right. I will change my answer if that proves to be the case :-)

Comment: @Alex is correct, I am forced to use specific concepts and resources. The hard thing is, I can't use anything not mentioned in class. popen() is somewhat forbidden for me in this case. I don't know if there is a simple way for doing it without popen()...

Comment: @cnicutar I am sorry, but I still don't seem to understand where do I connect the ends of the pipe. To the message queue from which I read?

Comment: The toupper() happened to be the right solution for me. Thank you all.